# getstream: is it safe to expose the API key to the public?

Tags: getstream-io

I noticed that a `GET` on a notification feed responds with a `next` attribute containing the API key. Not the secret, just the API key.

I'm curious whether this is safe to expose to an end user?

Example:

```
"next": "/api/v1.0/feed/notification/user8/?id_lt=8a4ba960-76fc-11e7-8080-800139637857&api_key=blahblahblahblah&limit=1&location=unspecified&offset=0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data payload you send to any of our API endpoints is encoded using your API secret into a JSON Web Token payload in the header for most calls. And guessing your very long API secret to properly encode anything would take an awfully long time, so yes we feel it's safe.

Also, you cannot log into the dashboard using your API credentials in any way so your billing information is safe (we still recommend turning on two-factor authentication in the dashboard though)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So then if I understand correctly, it's not possible to create or read any activity with only the API key. If so, great, but I'm curious what the purpose of including it on the query string is? Isn't it redundant to the data in the authorization header?

Comment: Correct, you can't do anything with only the api_key. The batch endpoints require different authentication methods, which is why we have a mix of `?api_key=` query parameter and `X-Api-Key` header. JWT-based endpoints have an `Authentication` header which contains the JWT payload. You can read more about the authentication setups on our REST documentation page if you're curious. https://getstream.io/docs_rest/